# Can we clean up [rabbitmq]?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

Since there aren't many people who regularly see questions tagged [rabbitmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rabbitmq), we routinely wind up with a lot of junk under that tag. My concern is that this makes good questions harder to find (though maybe Google searches don't find the bad ones easily).

Would any of you care to take a look and do some community moderation? Is there any other way to get more attention onto those questions?

Comment: You mean that tag is actually worse than C, C++, Android etc?

Comment: The tag is not working.  Abysmal answer rate, nobody earns any rep, several ranking experts quit contributing.  Looks to me it just lost its critical mass, if it ever had any.  Tough to build an active community when a product gets used by so many different languages.  The product owner doesn't seem thrilled either, real support happens in the mailing list.  Which does look healthy.

Comment: @HansPassant - yes, I'm not too happy about that. I think a mailing list is pretty 1990's, if you ask me.

Comment: That it is old, it doesn't mean it doesn't work. If that's what most believe to be the best way to get support, lets them knock themselves out.

Comment: Honestly, [rabbitmq] doesn't seem worse than other tags, it's just that nobody seems to care. [php] would look the same if it weren't for a handful of users who keep it somewhat clean, there's just a higher volume there